# Why does my prolog predicate only work with an even number of elements in its list?

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

My predicate eo is supposed to function as so,

```
?- eo([a,b,c,d,e,f],L).

L = [b,d,f]
```

My code right now is,

```
eo([], []).
eo([_,X|L], [X | R]) :-
    eo(L, R).
```

But it only works when the given list as an even number of elements. When given a list with an odd number of elements, it just outputs false. Any advice?

EDIT:

```
?- eo([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],L).

L = [b,d,f]
```

is the expected results for an odd number of elements in the list.

Comment: Look at the simplest case: what should it do with a list of just one element? You don't have any clause that handles this. Since the recursive call always reduces the length of the list by 2, all lists of odd length will eventually hit the single element case, hence they currently fail.

Comment: waht is the expected result in case of odd number of elements ? please update your question with the results in both case odd and even .

Comment: @EchoMike444 updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is working

```
eo([],[]).
eo([_],[]).
eo([_,X|L],[X|R]) :- eo(L,R).
```

You need to have the second line that handle the list of one element ,

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much. One more question though. How do I modify the code to deal with sublists? For example, if my list contained a sublist, how would I modify the code to affect the sublist's elements too (as in remove every other element in the sublist as well)?

Comment: with sublists , you increase the complexity of the problem . Please provide more informations , and some code .

Answer (score 0):

QuickCheck can help no only in finding failing queries for buggy predicates but also **narrow** down those failing queries to the most simple one. In this case, using Logtalk's `lgtunit` tool QuickCheck support:

```
?- lgtunit::quick_check(eo(+list(character), -list(character))).
*     quick check test failure:
*       eo([d],[])
false.
```

Comparing the failing query to your code, makes it clear the bug pointed out in the (other) answers and the comments: no clause for handling an input list with a single element.

But do remember that QuickCheck generates **random** test queries and thus is only able to show a failing query, not proving correctness.